# Getting None value for a pyomo Variable after solving the model

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I have solved a model called `llbp`. The status for the result object is coming as **optimal** . But, for one of the variables the values is coming as `None` and hence I am unable to access the objective value.

```
In: if (llbp_result.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (llbp_result.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print ("this is feasible and optimal")
```

```
Out: this is feasible and optimal
```

```
In: llbp.obj.expr()
```

```
Out: ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: x[89]
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object x[89]
```

```
In: llbp.x[89].value == None
```

```
Out: True
```

Comment: How are you calling the solver?  Can you include a minimal working example that shows the behavior?

Comment: I am solving the model iteratively and creating the model in a function. Following is the code that calls the solver: `solver = SolverFactory('cbc',executable=r"C:\Cbc-2.10-win32-msvc14\bin\cbc",options={'sec':1800})`

Comment: That creates the solver interface object.  We will need to know how you are actually invoking the solver (this would be a line similar to `llbp_result = solver.solve(...)`).

Comment: I am invoking the solver using: `llbp_result = solver.solve(llbp,tee=False)`

Answer (score 2):

What @rodri says is probably true, that a variable's value is given as `None` because it does not appear in any constraint or in the objective function.

To address that, you can use `initialize=0` when you define the variables. For example:

`model.V = Var(initialize=0)`

Of course you can also add any other arguments related to Pyomo sets, `within` statements etc.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. In my case, the solver put some variables to `None` because they didn't appear in the objective function or any other constraint. Or, rather, they appeared multiplied by a parameter with value 0. Check if this is also happening in your model

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As you can see, I am evaluating the objective function and getting an error. This means the variable that is None is in the objective function expression.